# What is a good way to mutate object attribute from id to actual id reference

Tags: python, pymongo, fastapi, pydantic

I am making an API with an endpoint which should return an object like this

```py
{
'id': 'asdqwe123randomnessxxyyzz',
'title': 'some title',
'owner': {
    'id': 'qwersdaf4132otherrandomness',
    'name': 'some name',
    },
}
```

and in the database the objects look like this

```py
{
'id': 'asdqwe123randomnessxxyyzz',
'title': 'some title',
'owner_id': 'qwersdaf4132otherrandomness',
}
```

I am using pydantic models for my API and currently I am returning the objects like this

```py
return [Object(**x) for x in mongo_db_column.find()]
```

where `x` is the json from the database

the class for Object looks like this:

```py
from pydantic import Basemodel, Optional

class Object(Basemodel):
    id: Optional[str]
    title: str
    owner_id: str
```

and the owner class looks like this:

```py
class Owner(Basemodel):
    id: Optional[str]
    name: str
```

So my question is if it is possible to use some method from `Basemodel` to instantiate it so that the `owner_id` will be converted into an instance of `Owner`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve your goal.

First would be to keep pydantic models "dumb" (meaning they are no tied to the db by any means) and init them with already aggregated data from the database.

You would have to rewrite your models so that `Object` model refers to `Owner`.

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Owner(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    name: str


class Object(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    title: str
    owner: Owner
```

And provided that you have aggregated data so that:

```
data = {
    'id': 'asdqwe123randomnessxxyyzz',
    'title': 'some title',
    'owner': {
        'id': 'qwersdaf4132otherrandomness',
        'name': 'some name',
    },
}
Object(**data)  # this would produce desired value
```

You could also load referred owner from the Basemodel field's pre-validation:

```
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator


class Owner(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    name: str


class Object(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    title: str
    owner: Owner = Field(..., alias='owner_id')

    @validator('owner', pre=True)
    def load_owner(cls, owner_id):
        if isinstance(owner_id, str):
            # perform loading from owner collection
            # e.g. owner = owner_collection.find_one({'id': owner_id})
            return owner
        return owner_id
```

This way your code should produce desired value.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!